# BIRT Reporting tool - I had to added header details but it is coming in details section, can any one please guide and resolve

Tags: database, birt, birt-emitter, birt-deapi

I have created Report Development on Eclipse BIRT reporting tool and created sample report and when I tried to enter image description here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Ten.jpg)? Can anyone help in this regard.

Pictures are attached for your Reference

to add header components, It was showing in details columns.

expecting to show the header columns at the top of the report not in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess because your screenshot doesn't show the outline view, which would show the structure of the layout. You better reset the perspective.

It looks like your header information (the labels in the row with the gray background) isn't placed in the header row, but in an additional detail row instead, for whatever reason.

Just move the labels one row up into the one which is marked as header row.
Then remove the superfluous first detail row.